# Update property of two objects in list based on matching objects in other list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two Pojos:

```
class Object1 {

    public Object1(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String id;
    private Integer value1;
    private Integer value2;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(Integer value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public Integer getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(Integer value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

```
public class Object2 {

    private String id;
    private Integer value;

    public Object2(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I have two lists of these objects where the objects have the same Id. I want to set value2 of the Objects in the list l1 based on the value of the objects in l2 by setting the value from the object2 value field where the Ids of both objects match.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object1  o1_1 = new Object1("asdf");
        Object1 o1_2 = new Object1("qwert");
        List<Object1> l1 = Arrays.asList(o1_1, o1_2);

        Object2  o2_1 = new Object2("asdf");
        o2_1.setValue(123);
        Object2 o2_2 = new Object2("qwert");
        o2_2.setValue(456);
        List<Object2> l2 = Arrays.asList(o2_1, o2_2);


        l1.forEach(object1 -> l2.stream()
                .filter(object2 -> object1.getId().equals(object2.getId()))
                .forEach(object2 -> object1.setValue2(object2.getValue())));

    }
}
```

How would I do that efficiently with the java stream API?

Is this solution correct?
The complexity is O(n²) right? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You're already using the Stream API, what do you expect ?

Comment: are both the list of size `N`? could they have duplicates based on the `id`?

Comment: Probably the only way to be more efficient is to use a `Map` and/or storing the two matching objects as some sort of tuple/pair type object under the single ID, or maybe even composing the two if the model allows for it. But that's data structure optimisation, not algorithmic.

Comment: If you care about performance, you could convert one of the lists to a lookup map with ID as a key and then update the other list. It would have a complexity of O(N).

Comment: @azro: just wanted to check whether my solution is correct can be improved

Comment: @Naman, no duplicates possible, both the same size

Comment: @Amongalen: could you help me with an example? Not sure what you have on your mind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about performance, you could convert one of the lists to a lookup map with ID as a key and then update the other list. It would have a complexity of O(N).

You would create a lookup map like so:

```
Map<Integer, Object2> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Object2 obj : l2) {
    map.put(obj.getId(), obj);
}
```

Or with Streams:

```
Map<Integer, Object2> map = l2.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object2::getId, obj -> obj));
```

Now you can iterate over first list and update elements with value with help of the map.

```
l1.stream().forEach(o1 -> o1.setValue2(map.get(o1.getId()).getValue()));
```

Alternatively, if `Object2` only has `id` and `value`, you could even create a `map<id, value>`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Object2 obj : list) {
    map.put(obj.getId(), obj.getValue());
}

l1.stream().forEach(o1 -> o1.setValue2(map.get(o1.getId())));
```

Comment: Thank you :) I will probably accept this answer, I'm just waiting for some more feedback on my solution (whether it was correct and what the time complexity of my solution is - O(n²) correct?)